# Binning of event-lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large file (list) with events, each of which contains many observables and is thus a list by itself. The structure of the event list is then as follows:

{{a1,b1,c1,d1,...},{a2,b2,c2,d2,...},......{an,bn,cn,dn,....}}

I now want to reorganize these event-lists such that they are binned with respect to one chosen variable, say c.

1. How could this be done in Mathematica?
2. After binning events with respect to c I would then like to bin further, with respect to, say, b. How to do that?

Comment: You are very much more likely to get an answer to this sort of question if you can provide a data set to apply it to.  It doesn't need to be your full data set, a toy example would do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there has been no feedback from the OP for an extended period of time. That is why it is desirable to have a concrete question along with the required answer to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If "bin" means some kind of sorting you could repeatedly apply `SortBy`

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 5}]; 

s3=SortBy[list, (#[[3]] &)]
s31=SortBy[s3, (#[[1]] &)]
```

Comment: Or `SortBy[list, (#[[1]] && #[[3]] &)]` in one call to `SortBy`

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.  Generate a very simple 2D data set

```
n = 100;
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];

ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"]
```

[image]

Cluster this by the second value in each list

```
clusters1 = 
  FindClusters[data, 3, 
   DistanceFunction -> (Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] &)];

ListPlot[clusters1, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"]
```

[image]

Now apply clustering independently to each of these clusters

```
clusters2 = 
  FindClusters[#, 2, 
     DistanceFunction -> (Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] &)] & /@ clusters1;

ListPlot[Flatten[clusters2, 1], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"]
```

[image]

Obviously, this approach can be applied to more complicated data sets, though visualising the results will be harder.  You would probably want to look at the documentation for `FindCluster` to understand how it works and whether it is appropriate to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want count the number of elements of your columns whose values lie in successive bins of certain width?

Let's say you have each string of 3 elements:

```
data = Table[{0, 1.25 Cos[i/100], 0} + RandomReal[{0, 2}, 3], 
             {i, 1, 100}];
```

The `dc` function makes the diagrams of bin counts:

```
dc = BarChart[BinCounts[#, {0, 2, 0.05}], ImageSize -> 400] &;
```

Just put into dc the right sub-lists:

```
Manipulate[
 Column@(dc@data[[All, par]]),
 {par, 1, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to just count events in a given bin, but move the whole event (=sublist) to a bin determined by a given range of variables c_n. After that is done, then in a second step, I would like to bin all events in the c-bin, with the second subbin described by a range in dn.